# Iperf3 commands with python script

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone tell difference between iPerf and iPerf3? while using it with client-server python script,what are the dependencies?And what are the alternatives to iPerf?

Answer (score 0):

iperf vs iperf3 from wikipedia

> A rewrite of iperf from scratch, with the goal of a smaller, simpler
>   code base and a library version of the functionality that can be used
>   in other programs, called iperf3, was started in 2009. The first
>   iperf3 release was made in January 2014. The website states: "iperf3
>   is not backwards compatible with iperf2.x".

Alternatives are Netcat, Bandwidth Test Controller (BWCTL), ps-performance toolkit, iXChariot, jperf, Lanbench, NetIO-GUI, Netstress.

Answer (score 0):

iperf2 and iperf3 are completely separate code bases, although they both had their roots as bandwidth testers.  iperf2, iperf3, and other tools all have their respective strengths.

One of my colleagues has written up some notes on these and other tools here:

http://fasterdata.es.net/performance-testing/network-troubleshooting-tools/

Also see the iperf3 FAQ:

http://software.es.net/iperf/faq.html